# SQL to XML transfer of data

Tags: sql, xml, transfer

Ok have been trying to learn SQL to XML the last few days and this is what I have been able to teach my self thus far.

```
`SELECT distinct StudentItem.foldername AS "foldername", StudentItem.status, StudentItem.vhrid, StudentItem.firstname, StudentItem.middleinitial, StudentItem.lastname,
dbo.getEnumDescript(StudentType, 'StudentType') AS title,
StudentItem.email, 
dbo.getEnumDescript(OfficeLocation, 'OfficeLocation') AS Office,
practices.id as 'StudentItem/practices/practice/id',
practices.name as 'StudentItem/practices/practice/name',
schoolItem.Name as 'StudentItem/bio/schools/schoolItem/schoolname',
schoolItem.schoolYear as 'lawyerItem/bio/schools/schoolItem/schoolyear'
FROM [dbo].[Student] as lawyerItem
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[StudentGroups] as aprac on StudentItem.vhrid = aprac.vhrid
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PracticeGroups] as practices on aprac.PracticeGroupID = practices.ID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[StudentEducation] as schoolItem on StudentItem.vhrid = schoolItem.vhrid
where StudentItem.vhrid='50330'
FOR XML path, ROOT ('StudentItem'), ELEMENTS;`
```

What I get is this

```
`<StudentItems>
  <row>
    <foldername>susan.wissink</foldername>
    <status>1</status>
    <vhrid>50330</vhrid>
    <firstname>Susan</firstname>
    <middleinitial>M.</middleinitial>
    <lastname>Wissink</lastname>
    <title>Student leader</title>
    <email>swissink@blank.com</email>
    <Office>Phoenix</Office>
    <StudentItem>
      <practices>
        <practice>
          <id>681</id>
          <name>Real Estate Finance and Lending</name>
        </practice>
      </practices>
      <bio>
        <schools>
          <schoolItem>
            <schoolname>&lt;i&gt;Best in America®&lt;/i&gt;, ASU</schoolname>
            <schoolyear>2016</schoolyear>
          </schoolItem>
        </schools>
      </bio>
    </StudentItem>
  </row>
  <row>
    <foldername>susan.wissink</foldername>
    <status>1</status>
    <vhrid>50330</vhrid>
    <firstname>Susan</firstname>
    <middleinitial>M.</middleinitial>
    <lastname>Wissink</lastname>
    <title>Student leader</title>
    <email>swissink@blank.com</email>
    <Office>Phoenix</Office>
    <StudentItem>
      <practices>
        <practice>
          <id>681</id>
          <name>Real Estate Finance and Lending</name>
        </practice>
      </practices>
      <bio>
        <schools>
          <schoolItem>
            <schoolname>&lt;i&gt;Best in America®&lt;/i&gt;, UOP</schoolname>
            <schoolyear>2011-2015</schoolyear>
          </schoolItem>
        </schools>
      </bio>
    </StudentItem>
  </row>`
```

But I'm trying to get the all the practices and schools to show up as one entry for the guy that. More or less I'm trying to get it to look like below.

```
`<StudentItems>
  <row>
    <foldername>susan.wissink</foldername>
    <status>1</status>
    <vhrid>50330</vhrid>
    <firstname>Susan</firstname>
    <middleinitial>M.</middleinitial>
    <lastname>Wissink</lastname>
    <title>Student leader</title>
    <email>swissink@blank.com</email>
    <Office>Phoenix</Office>
    <StudentItem>
      <practices>
        <practice>
          <id>681</id>
          <name>Real Estate Finance and Lending</name>
          <id>683</id>
          <name>Business and Finance</name>
        </practice>
      </practices>
      <bio>
        <schools>
          <schoolItem>
            <schoolname>&lt;i&gt;Best in America®&lt;/i&gt;, UOP</schoolname>
            <schoolyear>2011-2015</schoolyear>
            <schoolname>&lt;i&gt;Best in America®&lt;/i&gt;, ASU</schoolname>
            <schoolyear>2016</schoolyear>
          </schoolItem>
        </schools>
      </bio>
    </StudentItem>
  </row>`
```

Any help would be welcome. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample data, it's difficult to write code and test for.  But generally what you need to do is to create sub-queries to create your `practice` and `schoolItem` XML nodes.  Something like this:

```
SELECT distinct StudentItem.foldername AS "foldername", 
    StudentItem.status, 
    StudentItem.vhrid, 
    StudentItem.firstname, 
    StudentItem.middleinitial, 
    StudentItem.lastname,
    dbo.getEnumDescript(StudentType, 'StudentType') AS title,
    StudentItem.email, 
    dbo.getEnumDescript(OfficeLocation, 'OfficeLocation') AS Office,
    (
        select practices.id, practices.name
        from [dbo].[StudentGroups] as aprac
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PracticeGroups] as practices 
        on aprac.PracticeGroupID = practices.ID 
        where StudentItem.vhrid = aprac.vhrid
        FOR XML path(''), type
    ) 'StudentItem/practices/practice',
    (
        select Name schoolname, schoolYear
        from [dbo].[StudentEducation] schoolItem
        where StudentItem.vhrid = schoolItem.vhrid
        FOR XML path(''), type
    ) 'StudentItem/bio/schools/schoolItem'
FROM [dbo].[Student] as StudentItem
where StudentItem.vhrid='50330'
FOR XML path, ROOT ('StudentItem');
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is now returning the what I want for the most part. The part that is still messing me up is the StudentEducation. I seem to be getting a syntax error near 'for' in the xml path code. I have changed out name for schoolitem.name, and schoolitem.schoolyear. still no dice.

Comment: With farther testing I seem to be able to do one or the other, School or Practice. Either one comes out the way I want them, however when I combine them like they are in your code. I get the above xml error.

Comment: oops... there was a missing comma after 'StudentItem/practices/practice'... I added it to the answer.

Comment: Well bugger me that was it Thank you for your help Brian.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you found the answer useful and mark it "accepted" it helps others see that you found the answer useful and also gives the answerer a little cred points.  :)

Comment: One more question is I wanted to separate the practices and school items to make it easier to read, how would I do that, a distinct command with SQL?  To get it to look like in the next post.

Comment: `      <practices>
        <practice>
          <id>681</id>
          <name>Real Estate Finance and Lending</name>
       </practice>
      <practice>
          <id>683</id>
          <name>Business and Finance</name>
        </practice>
      </practices>
`

Comment: Just take the /practice off the subquery column alias and prefix the alias on each column the select: select practices.id 'practice/ID', practices.name 'practice/name'.